# Passing data between 2 activities when one activity is retaining task state?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

I have 2 activities in which i have to get data from activity 1 and then move to activity 2 to get additional data and then move back to previous activity (activity 1) with combined data to be send using retrofit.
Here activity 1 is retaining task state = true so when getting intent.putdata from activity 2 no data is passed to activity 1.
So how to pass data to activity 1 while retaining its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shared Preferences described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences